# Mosby странное поведение c RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, mosby

Использую `Mosby`. Не могу понять почему в одном случае отрабатывает в другом случае нет. Хотя по сути операции одни и те же.

Мой базовый класс

```
 abstract class BaseLceListFragment<M, V : MvpLceView<List<M>>, P : MvpPresenter<V>>
    : BaseLceFragment<RelativeLayout, List<M>, V, P>() {

    lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    lateinit var adapter: BaseAdapter<M, BaseListViewHolder<M>>

    var scrollPosition: Int = 0
    var dataInitialSetComplete: Boolean = false

    abstract fun createAdapter(): BaseAdapter<M, BaseListViewHolder<M>>

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = createAdapter()
        initRecyclerView()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun setData(data: List<M>) {
        adapter.updateItems(data)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        if (!dataInitialSetComplete) {
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition)
            dataInitialSetComplete = true
        }
        showContent()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        scrollPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        dataInitialSetComplete = false
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        adapter.clearAdapter()
    }

    fun addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration: DividerItemDecoration) {
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    }
}
```

И вот выполняю запрос на сервер. Всё отлично работает и отображает.

```
  notesUseCase.execute(Consumer { response ->
        noteItems = response.noteResponse?.noteItems!!
        preferenceManager.setNoteTypeItems(
                NoteTypesUtils
                        .getNoteTypeItem(preferenceManager.getNoteTypeItems(), response.typeNoteResponse?.results))
        run {
            ifViewAttached { view: NotesView -> view.setData(sortByDate(filterNotes())) }
        }
    },
            Consumer {
                run {
                    it.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, caseId)
```

Ну если я передам так элементы

```
noteItems = mutableListOf()`

   noteItems.add(NoteItem("QW", "qwer", Date(), "QWRRR", NoteTypeItem(true, "QERerer", 1)))
    noteItems.add(NoteItem("QW", "qwer", Date(), "QWRRR", NoteTypeItem(true, "QERerer", 2)))
    noteItems.add(NoteItem("QW", "qwer", Date(), "QWRRR", NoteTypeItem(true, "QERerer", 2)))
    noteItems.add(NoteItem("QW", "qwer", Date(), "QWRRR", NoteTypeItem(true, "QERerer", 3)))

    run {
       ifViewAttached { view: NotesView -> view.setData(sortByDate(filterNotes())) }
   }`
```

То они не отображаются в recyclerView.  Хотя если смотреть по логам и дебагу. Adapter имеет 4 элемента. С чем связано это странное поведение?

И на этом странность не закончиться. Если я ицилиализирую первым способ( не обязательно с запроса подставлять данные), я могу уже изменять данные вторым способом. Ну вот без первого не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в методе `OnResume()`. А именно в `adapter.clearAdapter()`. Он не нужен

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        adapter.clearAdapter()
    }
```